# Convert to a board covering Single-board Computers

Tags: discussion

I'm personally an owner of 2 Raspberry Pis and just got my shipment of Cubietruck (Cubieboard3). Unfortunately, this product is not very well documented anywhere or the documentation is outdated. The forums are not particularly active either.

I've been looking around the stack exchange network to look for support for my Cubietruck and come to realise that there isn't a board for Single-board Computers.

There are several different manufacturers and Single-board computers in the market and their users range from experienced to complete command line newbies.

I was wondering if it might be a smarter option to convert this existing Raspberry Pi board to a board covering Single-board Computers as a whole? Just like how Stack Overflow umbrellas over all programming languages.

Raspberry Pi, Beaglebone, Beagleboard, Cubietruck, Cubieboard could all be tags in this board, just as how PHP, C++, Python are tags in SO. Existing questions on the RasPi board could all be tagged with the raspberry pi tag after the conversion.

In Area51, there is a proposal for a board for Beaglebone/board. I believe there may be overlapping topics (such as general getting the *nix OS configured stuff) that will be applicable to several Single-board Computers regardless of make and therefore having separate boards for each make of Single-board Computers will be inefficient.

Using the pretty much established RasPi board as a starting point, I think that many users and enthusiasts will benefit from such an integration.

Comment: I agree, but there are some heavy voices against this.