# Cools names for the RasPi site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I realize this site is still in beta, and compared to larger sites, it has a pretty dull name. There's Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Different, Arqade, and then, Raspberry Pi. Oh yeah, and same with Electrical Engineering. BUt anyway...

Is there anyone able to change the site name to make it more catchy/clever?
I was brainstorming a bit myself:

Credit Card Computing
Pi r Squared
Raspberry

Comment: Couldn't change the name of the site so you changed your user name?

Comment: Haha, kind of. It was 2 years outdated. Now it matches my google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, and I would need a better reason than the current name is boring to make such a suggestion to the Stack Overflow powers that be.It would have negative effects on SEO, finadability, memorability and usability. Boring though it may appear you should remember cutesy (like Pi r Squared) goes out of fashion - factual/literal doesn't.

Ask yourself these questions:

- How did you first find the site?
- What is the site Pi r Squared about? As someone with a Raspberry Pi problem why would I think this was the right site?
- Did you visit the site for the title or the information?
- Why if our biggest source of traffic is Google would we want to make a change that would be detrimental to those googling the site? There is something like an 80% chance that you found this site via google.

Then try this:

Type Raspberry Pi and any other word (related to electronics, computing, programming etc. into google and see how many results are to this site on the first page of the search results.

In addition to the above we recently had a suggestion made to [merge](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/should-this-site-merge-with-the-embedded-programming-design-proposal?rq=1) (see [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/what-would-you-think-about-broadening-the-topic-to-include-arduino-robotics-and?rq=1) as well)  with several smaller SO sites, including Arduino and robotics.The biggest reason for not doing that was that we have a very specific focus that is seen as a benefit. We have also been asked multiple times about adding support for the [Banana Pi](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/are-banana-orange-etc-questions-on-topic?s=2%7C0.5437) and other [similar boards](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/convert-to-a-board-covering-single-board-computers?rq=1). There was no real support for this either from the community.

While I firmly believe the only dumb question is one not asked. I would suggest that next time you invest a little more time in researching the prevailing opinions and as a relatively new user of this site and Stack exchange in general that you invest a little more time in getting to know and understand the culture.

Comment: Allrighty then. Forgot about SEO, people searching for raspberry pi and whatnot. Sorry about that, just I thought it was a bit dull.

Comment: what about a Logo? :-)

Comment: If you had looked into this you would have seen that this is a feature of graduation.

Comment: Also, by posting it as a comment to instead of a new question. It was unlikely that anyone but me would see (I only saw it because I own the answer).

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just asking you

Comment: Just a random thought